# Select occurrences that doesn't have a certain value in field

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table with fields A and B:

```
| A | B |
---------
| 1 | p |
| 1 | f |
| 1 | t |
| 2 | p |
| 2 | f |
```

I am trying to construct a query finding all the A's that doesn't also have a 't' for B somewhere.

So for this data the output should just be

```
| A |
-----
| 2 |
```

as 2 doesn't have 't' listed anywhere in field B

I tried doing `SELECT DISTINCT A FROM table WHERE B!='t'`, but that logic is flawed as 1 also contains a row with `B!='t'`. I also tried various variations of `GROUP BY`, but I am stuck.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `group by` and `having` for this:

```
select a
from t
group by a
having sum(b = 't') = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT A
FROM mytable
GROUP BY A
HAVING SUM(B = 't') = 0
```

The `HAVING` clause filters out `A` groups that contain at least one record with `B = 't'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY AND HAVING Clause :

```
 SELECT A
 FROM 
 GROUP BY A
 HAVING SUM(B = 't') = 0;
```